# How do I trigger a function to execute after external HTML is loaded?

Tags: html, load, external, jquery, jquery-on

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#loader").load("external.html");

    $("#buttonClickText").live('click', function() {
        $("#buttonClickText").text("Text changed after button click.");
    });

    // MYSTERY FUNCTION
    $("#pageLoadText").text("Text changed after external HTML was loaded.");
    //

});
```

External HTML:

```
<div id="buttonClickText">
    This text changes when clicked.
</div>

<div id="pageLoadText">
    This text should have changed when external HTML was loaded, but didn't.
</div>
```

Main HTML (just showing the relevant tag):

```
<div id="loader"></div>
```

Also, I know .live() is deprecated for jQuery 1.7+, I'm guessing the solution will be similar using .on()

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from http://api.jquery.com/load/:

> This method is the simplest way to fetch data from the server. It is
>   roughly equivalent to $.get(url, data, success) except that it is a
>   method rather than global function and it has an implicit callback
>   function. When a successful response is detected (i.e. when textStatus
>   is "success" or "notmodified"), .load() sets the HTML contents of the
>   matched element to the returned data.

Just pass a function as the second argument.

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html', function() {
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew it would be a simple answer but I couldn't figure it out

Answer (score 1):

below is the solution for the issue:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#loader").load("external.html", function()
        {
            $("#pageLoadText").text("Text changed after external HTML was loaded.");
        }
    );

$("#buttonClickText").live('click', function() {
    $("#buttonClickText").text("Text changed after button click.");
});
```

});